# VSCode showing error while running C++ program on g++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, g++

I ran this C++ program ([Code on gfg](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/PE9tUeSw9A)) on VSCode using the run button and it exits with code=1 and shows this message :

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\pawar\OneDrive\Desktop\cp\" && g++ 5.cpp -o 5 && "c:\Users\pawar\OneDrive\Desktop\cp\"5
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cassert:44:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:33,
                 from 5.cpp:44:
c:\mingw\include\assert.h:38:38: error: conflicting declaration of C function 'void _assert(const char*, const char*, long long int)'
 _CRTIMP void __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _assert (const char*, const char*, int) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NORETURN;
                                      ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cassert:44:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:33,
                 from 5.cpp:6:
c:\mingw\include\assert.h:38:38: note: previous declaration 'void _assert(const char*, const char*, int)'
 _CRTIMP void __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _assert (const char*, const char*, int) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NORETURN;
[Done] exited with code=1 in 3.051 seconds
```

The program ran successfully on Codeforces and Codechef ide,
But did not run on Geeksforgeeks ide(SIGABRT error) and VSCode. Can someone help me how to fix this, so that it runs on VSCode, is it something to de with the compiler used, please guide?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `#define int ll` this looks harmful.

Comment: Did you download the development package?

Comment: @PHD Yes, I use VSCode for compiling C++ often and it never showed such error. Other C++ programs compile without any problem.

Comment: @MikeCAT I use that line often and it works fine. I tried running the code removing it but still doesn't work.

Comment: Note that you have included this line twice: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. Having it only once is already considered problematic

Comment: Thanks @Damien , that was the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #include<bits/stdc++.h>

This line was included twice, which caused the error.

Comment: Good it works. Now, you may be interested reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h